# php search array key and get value

Tags: php

I was wondering what is the best way to search keys in an array and return it's  value. Something like array_search but for keys. Would a loop be the best way?

Array:

```
Array([20120425] => 409 [20120426] => 610 [20120427] => 277
      [20120428] => 114 [20120429] => 32 [20120430] => 304
      [20120501] => 828 [20120502] => 803 [20120503] => 276 [20120504] => 162)
```

Value I am searching for : 20120504

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The key is already the ... ehm ... *key*

```
echo $array[20120504];
```

If you are unsure, if the key exists, test for it

```
$key = 20120504;
$result = isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;
```

Minor addition:

```
$result = @$array[$key] ?: null;
```

One may argue, that `@` is bad, but keep it serious: This is more readable and straight forward, isn't?

Update: With PHP7 my previous example is possible without the error-silencer

```
$result = $array[$key] ?? null;
```

Comment: as I thought, allot of different answers to this. This works great and is the simplest.

Comment: `The key is already the ... ehm ... key` - this is really helpful :) In the heat of the moment one can really forget the obvious. Thanks for saving me time!

Comment: Wow... the whole "KISS" thing comes into play here. I was working on this "problem" for an hour now and all the google searches lead to a 1 liner!  `$result = isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;`

Answer (score 12):

```
array_search('20120504', array_keys($your_array));
```

Comment: @Matthew: OP did state: "Value I am searching for : 20120504". So it's a safe assumption that he knows what he is looking for.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php

// Checks if key exists (doesn't care about it's value).
// @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
if (array_key_exists(20120504, $search_array)) {
  echo $search_array[20120504];
}

// Checks against NULL
// @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
if (isset($search_array[20120504])) {
  echo $search_array[20120504];
}

// No warning or error if key doesn't exist plus checks for emptiness.
// @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
if (!empty($search_array[20120504])) {
  echo $search_array[20120504];
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example straight from PHP.net

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}
```

in the foreach you can do a comparison of each key to something that you are looking for

Comment: Well I did not provide it since it it 99% there but the code in the foreach statement would look like this

`foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
if($a[$k] ==='20120504'){
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}
}`

Answer (score -3):

For get last value in multidimensional array and order ascending,

```
    function lastvalue($array, $key)
    {  
        $a = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
                $a[] = $array[$i][$key];
        }
       sort($a);
       return $a[$i-1];
    }

    $a=array(
            array("row" => 2, "column" => 6),
            array("row" => 2, "column" => 3), 
            array("row" => 2, "column" => 7)
           );

    echo lastvalue($a, "column"); //result = 7
```