# Return key values from first array whose key is in second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays I want to search from first array by key only which i have in second array and as third array i want to print result:

```
$colldata=array("bench-press-rod"=>'',"adidas-classic-backpack"=>'93549559913',"adidas-classic-backpack-legend-ink-multicolour"=>'',"puma-suede-classic-regal"=>'93549920361,93549723753');
$colldata2=array(0 => 'bench-press-rod',1 => 'adidas-classic-backpack');
```

Expected result:

```
array('bench-press-rod'=>'',"adidas-classic-backpack"=>'93549559913');
```

Comment: add your code first or check ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457685/php-search-array-key-and-get-value )

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line in PHP, using [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to swap the keys and values of the second array, and then [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to merge the two arrays on matching keys:

```
$colldata=array("bench-press-rod"=>'',"adidas-classic-backpack"=>'93549559913',"adidas-classic-backpack-legend-ink-multicolour"=>'',"puma-suede-classic-regal"=>'93549920361,93549723753');
$colldata2=array(0 => 'bench-press-rod',1 => 'adidas-classic-backpack');

print_r(array_intersect_key($colldata, array_flip($colldata2)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [bench-press-rod] => 
    [adidas-classic-backpack] => 93549559913
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/M5pqn)

Answer (score 1):

About the simplest I can come up with is to loop through the second array and add the matching key from the first array into the output.  If the item isn't present then it puts `Not found` in the output...

```
$output = [];
foreach ( $colldata2 as $item ) {
    $output[$item] = $colldata[$item] ?? 'Not found';
}
print_r($output);
```

gives..

```
Array
(
    [bench-press-rod] => 
    [adidas-classic-backpack] => 93549559913
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
$colldata=array("bench-press-rod"=>'',"adidas-classic-backpack"=>'93549559913',"adidas-classic-backpack-legend-ink-multicolour"=>'',"puma-suede-classic-regal"=>'93549920361,93549723753');
$colldata2=array(0 => 'bench-press-rod',1 => 'adidas-classic-backpack');

$result = [];
foreach ($colldata2 as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $colldata)) {
        array_push($result,$colldata[$value]);
    }            
}
echo '<pre/>';
print_r($result);
```