# How to keep specific key-value element in array and remove rest?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

$array_one

```
Array (
    [2018] => Array ()

    [2019] => Array
        (
            [5] => 2966
        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2930
            [1] => 2919
        )
)
```

2nd array is :

$costs

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [2789] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [2874] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0.5
                    [presta] => 1
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3786] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 7
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [315] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [325] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3793] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0.5
                    [presta] => 1.2
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3796] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 22
                    [presta] => 27.4
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3798] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3800] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 17
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3832] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 2
                    [presta] => 9
                    [log] => 0
                )

        )

    [2019] => Array
        (
            [2930] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 1
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3786] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 4
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [315] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3796] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 14
                    [presta] => 44
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [3834] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [2966] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [2930] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

            [2919] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I want to only keep those records in my 2nd array which are in 1st array and I want to unset remaining records from 2nd array

How to keep only those records in 2nds array which match the key values in 1st array?

Comment: Just use a couple of foreach loops and check the indexes match, if not use unset()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a looping version of the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456429/return-key-values-from-first-array-whose-key-is-in-second-array/57456600#57456600):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array_one as $key => $keys) {
    if (count($keys))
        $output[$key] = array_intersect_key($costs[$key], array_flip($keys));
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [2966] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )
        )
    [2020] => Array
        (
            [2930] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )    
            [2919] => Array
                (
                    [jh] => 0
                    [presta] => 0
                    [log] => 0
                )    
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/n5iUJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php),

```
foreach($costs as $k => &$val) // & to save value to value itself
{
    if(!empty($array_one[$k])){
        $val = array_intersect_key($val, $array_one[$k]);
    }
}
```

This will reduce no of iterations,

```
$result=[];
foreach ($array_one as $k => $val) {
    if (!empty($val))
        $result[$k] = array_intersect_key($costs[$k], array_flip($val));
}
print_r($result);
```

Ultimately, it will only keep only those index's data which is matching with `array_one`