# How to I return the first of matching key values?

Tags: php

I have an array that I want to search for a particular value, and then return the key. However, it's likely that there will be multiple matching values. What is the best way to return the key from the first  matching value?

```
$agent_titles = array(
    'agent_1' => sales,
    'agent_2' => manager, // The key I want to return
    'agent_3' => manager,       
    'agent_4' => director;
    );

    if (false !== $key = array_search('manager', $agent_titles)) {
        return $key;
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

In this scenario I would want to return 'agent_2'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One you fix the parse errors that exactly what your code does.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457685/php-search-array-key-and-get-value

Comment: By the way, remove the `;` in the line with     `'agent_4' => director;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usage of `array_search` was best solution
but try write your code simple as possible

```
$agent_titles=[
    'agent_1'=>'sales',
    'agent_2'=>'manager',
    'agent_3'=>'manager',
    'agent_4'=>'director',
];
return array_search('manager',$agent_titles);
```

Comment: will return `false` if not found , or `key` of array if found

Comment: thank you. so if there are multiple values of 'manager', it will only return the key of the first one - in this case 'agent_2', correct?

Comment: Yes , it will return `key` of first occurrence of `value` in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
public function blahblah($search_value = 'manager') {
    $agent_titles = [
     'agent_1' => sales,
     'agent_2' => manager,
     'agent_3' => manager,       
     'agent_4' => director,
    ];
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if($value == $search_value){
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getKeyByValue($input, $array) {

     foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) { 
        if ( $input == $value ) {
            return $key;
        }
     }
}

$agent_titles = array(
 'agent_1' => 'sales',
 'agent_2' => 'manager',
 'agent_3' => 'manager',       
 'agent_4' => 'director'
);

var_dump(getKeyByValue('manager', $agent_titles));
```