# PHP: How to search in array of objects and return the res

Tags: php, laravel-8

[image]

I have this Array of Objects and I want to search a string to all of the keys and return all the data of the matched objects.
I don't know if there's a duplicate of this question.
hope you guys can save my day.

the photo below is my code. I don't use eloquent btw and the data is from call-in SQL.

[image]

Below is the UI that I made.
[image]

Comment: can you provide a search example?

Comment: for example, i search for "s"
and I want to match it to all the value of the key like a loop in all of the key-value pairs and return all the key-value pairs that have a matched to "s"

Comment: and then you get for example: 132 => unit_measure, description? because the contain an 's' in the key name?

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Comment: and do you want to show all the properties or just the ones containing an 's' for example?

Comment: your question will be much clearer if you give a sample input and a desired output

Comment: all the properties sir.

Comment: Images of code is bad and limits people who use a screenreader. Consider editing your question and changing the image to formatted code.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `pluck` method from laravel(eloquent)

So something like this:

```
$plucked = $paginatedItems->pluck('item_code', 'unit_measure');

$plucked->all();
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate it so much. unfortunately, I am not using eloquent sorry I didn't clarify it in my question.

Comment: this answer is not relevant for the question

Comment: As far as I know the LenghtAwarePaginator is just a collection
You can use pluck on the collection as well

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to determine which approach would be best. However, there are a few ways of doing this. Below are some untested examples. But please use them as examples as there are far easier and better ways of doing this. I am simply trying to point you in the right direction.

```
$array = array_search([SEARCH TERM], array_keys([YOUR ARRAY]));
```

```
$results = [];
$array_keys = array_keys([YOUR ARRAY]);
for($i = 0; $i < count($array_keys); $i++) {
    if($array_keys[$i] == "[SEARCH TERM]") {
        $results[] = $[YOUR ARRAY][$i];
    }
}
```

Also try: [php search array key and get value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457685/php-search-array-key-and-get-value)

Edit: this is pure PHP - as you are using laravel, there are definitely better ways of doing this. Please read the documents for `pluck`